# problem with htaccess using with web browser

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, .htaccess

I have htaccess applied to some folder. When i open that folder using web browser then i get  user/password prompt.  If I enter wrong password , the i get some apache error.

But the problem i am getting is that even if i refresh the page i keep getting same error. Sometime i want to enter that again but keep getting same page without any user/password prompt. Looks like that user/password is stored in cache and it enetrs automatically.

is there any way to stop caching that details

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's probably at the specific web browser being used. In those situations, exiting the web browser completely and restarting it should do the trick.

Comment: i tried Firefox , IE and Chrome and all have same problem. I usually have many tabs open so i don't want to close all and open all again

Comment: Have you tested via a single tab instance to net out the situation?

Comment: i will try that out